# Are Sphinx Excerpts inserted into the data and thus accessible by MySql?

Tags: sphinx

In reading more about Excerpts:

http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=php_api_docs#buildexcerpts_documents_index_words_options

I am still unclear if the inserted tags are internally used by sphinx to format the final display text or if they actually added to the mysql:

```
before_match is a string to insert before each set of matching words. The default is '<b>'.
```

In other words if I changed the string to some non display htlm e.g. `<!-- START -->` for before_match and `<!-- END -->` for `after_match` I could then search on those in mysql or is the search still just a zone inside the index?

Answer (score 0):

No, buildExerpts does not touch the database at all. It does not even change the sphinx index either.

You simply pass it a block of text (or multiple) and a text query. And then it forms a new block of text for each, highlighting the provided terms. The new block(s) of text are provided by return.

... if you want to do something with that block of text (so can search it otherwise!) would then have save it somewhere for example.

(the 'inserted tags' you talk about, are just added in the new block of text, which is generally considered to be HTML, so would then just be displayed to the end user)